# Multithreads priority ouput not clear

Tags: java, multithreading, class, oop

I am really really confused with multithreading. I know this facts

"**Threading is unpredictable**"

Does this fact holds only for same Priority of threads ? If not then what is the need for setting the priority of threads.

By that I mean suppose this code:

```
public class Threadsync implements Runnable{
    Thread t;
    String str;
    public Threadsync(String name)
    {
        this.str=name;
        this.t=new Thread(this,name);
        this.t.start();
        this.t.setPriority(10);
    }
    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println("hello "+str);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Threadsync("thread1");       //1
        new Threadsync("thread2");       //2
        System.out.println("world");     //3 
    }
}
```

This was my code and I got output as
hello thread1 
world
hello thread2

No confusion about thread1 and thread2 but why main thread output message `world` before thread2 output message `hello thread2` even though thread2 has almost double priority than main thread. 
Thanks in advance . Detailed explanation would be highly appreciable

Comment: What happens if you call setPriority before start ?

Comment: Yet it was interesting to test :)

Comment: Why negative vote... If you think I'm wrong at something plz tell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Priority only comes i to play when when you are running more threads than you CPU or your OS can handle so they are properly all running at the same time.

If you use the Notify and Wait methods then the Thread with the highest priority waiting will get in the front off the que!

So there is the reason for using priority but be aware if a high priority Thread is calling a method to much there is a possibility the lower threads never will get lock in the que.

Comment: It comes into play when and if the OS so decides, and that isn't defined by Java.

Comment: @EJP does hat mean this statement is wrong "Higher priority thread is sure to be executed earlier than low priority thread"

Comment: Yes and no its the Java virtual machine that decide all java threads time slices.

Comment: @JeppeAndersen Means unpredictable is the only thing that we as developer can say about the sequence of thread execution

Comment: Yes only when the ques are bigger than the CPU/OS can handle (in Java) the java virtual machine will look at the priority.

Comment: @JeppeAndersen One more question by the time thread1 and thread2 get started . Then aren't there three runnable thread after that.If the threads are runnable then Isn't that means that they are ready to compete at same time for CPU time.

Comment: Don't understand the question :)

Comment: @JeppeAndersen Nice update to the question but still my doubt stands. "No matter how many threads I instantiate I keep on getting "world" as my second output .So there must be some logic"

Comment: @JeppeAndersen I think finally got my answer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Threading is unpredictable you where saying and you where right.
the JVM have many issues to handle beside your little threads. and even if you give priority you still can't know what will happen & when.
If you run your experiment with more threads, more processing to be done and multiple times you will see that...
but even though thy unpredictable they still very usefull.

Comment: but still sir how many threads I instantiate I keep on getting "world" as my second output .So there must be some logic

Comment: If you will run 7 threads with and print to screen in each thread "Tread N : i=#" where N is the thread number and i=# are values in FOR loop from 1 to 100000000, you will se that there is no logic, I guess you can see the priority really works in this situation - if you'll print the output to file

Answer (score 1):

When threads run is actually decided by the operating system's scheduler.  A thread's priority is, at best, *advice* you are giving the operating system - a hint it might or might not use.  For a long time on Linux, all threads ran at the same priority no matter what priority was set on them programmatically.

In short, setting the priority of a thread does not give you any guarantee of when it will run or how the operating system will actually prioritize it.  Your code needs to work even if the OS interprets your thread priorities backwards - that is, your code should never assume that thread priorities actually mean *anything*.  C.f. [this advice in Effective Java](http://books.google.com/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA286&lpg=PA286&dq=bloch+thread+scheduler+correctness&source=bl&ots=yYKgPlp5V_&sig=4iOhYNzri2z9JvKrChMIwwMVRjU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=XC5cUp-1JdS6kQeUzoGIDQ&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=bloch%20thread%20scheduler%20correctness&f=false).

Comment: Still the OS only give the Java virtual machine a time slice to its code and it will then run its threads

Comment: @Tim Boudreau So should i take setPriority just as waste of space in my code.

Comment: Pretty much.  If you know something is really important, it won't hurt to set it as high priority (or the converse), but don't depend on that actually determining execution order.

Answer (score 1):

From the Java language specification:

> Every thread has a priority. When there is competition for processing
>   resources, threads with higher priority are generally executed in
>   preference to threads with lower priority. **Such preference is not,
>   however, a guarantee that the highest priority thread will always be
>   running, and thread priorities cannot be used to reliably implement
>   mutual exclusion**.

However Threads normal priority, `Thread.NORM_PRIORITY` has the value `5`. According to my several test i have noticed that priority setting between `5` and `1` works with the child thread, though it stills let the `Main thread` to execute first as `Main` thread has the priority `5` as default.

Comment: yes. I just said that because i thought you are after whither we can prioritize child thread over Main. I am sorry that my wording was misleading.